# Rest API No action was found on the controller

Tags: c#, .net

I call your experience to help me solve a problem.
I have this code:

```
public class FanController : ApiController
{

    [ActionName("ImportAwb")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> ImportAwb([FromBody]JObject data) 
    {
        try
        {
            string username = data["username"].ToString();
            string clientId = data["clientId"].ToString();
            string userPass = data["userPass"].ToString();
            string fisier = data["fisier"].ToString();

            var responseString = await FanCourier.ImportAwbIntegrat(username, clientId, userPass, fisier);
            return Ok(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex);
        }
    }
```

If i left just one method like this, i can call it from Postman with no problem, but if i try to make another one, like this:

{

```
public class FanController : ApiController
{

    [ActionName("ImportAwb")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> ImportAwb([FromBody]JObject data) 
    {
        try
        {
            string username = data["username"].ToString();
            string clientId = data["clientId"].ToString();
            string userPass = data["userPass"].ToString();
            string fisier = data["fisier"].ToString();

            var responseString = await FanCourier.ImportAwbIntegrat(username, clientId, userPass, fisier);
            return Ok(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex);
        }
    }


    [ActionName("PrintareAwbHtml")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> PrintareAwbHtml([FromBody]FanCourier fanCourier)
    {
        try
        {
            var responseString =
                await fanCourier.PrintareAwbHtml(fanCourier);
            return Ok(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex);
        }

    }
```

The response from Postman call is:

```
"Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nImportAwb on type Courier.Rest.Controllers.FanController\r\nPrintareAwbHtml on type Courier.Rest.Controllers.FanController"
```

I was tried to add a `[Route("api/[controller]")]` before `public class FanController : ApiController` and the error was change to:

```
No action was found on the controller 'Fan' that matches the request.
```

I have tried to find something on the internet but i found nothing to help my situations.

Comment: Try to use [Route("specific-url")] attribute on your controller's methods directly. That tells aso.net to map urls and methods correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define routes for each of your actions so you know which will be called when specific API is called.

Use `[Route]` tag to accomplish that

```
    [ActionName("ImportAwb")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Action1")]
    public async Task<object> ImportAwb([FromBody]JObject data) 
    {
...
```

And from postman, call your endpoint with url being. `http://yoururl.com/Action1`.

(YourUrl would be the path you set up for this controller... might include /api or what you might have configured. Add /Action1 to the end of that url)

You **can** have multiple routes to the same URL as long as they are different methods (post, get, delete, patch etc.).